# Paypal Pro Iframe opencart

Tags: php, iframe, paypal, opencart

I got an email from Paypal saying (below). And I cant find anything to help me fix it, Im using the Opencart standard payment gateway called "PayPal Website Payment Pro iFrame" and I do not know how to update it. any help would be appreciated.

> We are contacting you regarding a change that you are required to make by 30th August 2015.

PayPal has detected that you have hard coded the following Pro Hosted Solution URL in your code:(Had to remove link)

PayPal does not recommend hard coding. Instead, you should read the URL from the button creation API response.

If you must hard code this URL, you need to update it to the following: https://securepayments.paypal.com/webap ... ionProcess

You can find comprehensive instructions regarding the required integration changes on our Technical Support Help Centre: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1231

Click the above link or visit the PayPal Technical Support Centre and search for article ID ‘1231’ or ‘Updating API Integration for Pro Hosted’ for instructions on ensuring that your payment processing is not interrupted when we stop supporting the current hardcoded URL.

Important: you must either read the URL from the button creation API response or update your hard code URL by no later than 30 August 2015. Otherwise, your existing hard coded Pro Hosted Solution URL will not be supported after that date.

If you require any additional support, our Merchant Technical Support team are on hand and ready to help. You can contact them by opening a ticket on ...

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I found out a little more from here, but no answers.
http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=191&t=146144

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue in the code for "PayPal Website Payment Pro iFrame" which its developer needs to fix or provide you with a workaround.  Have you contacted them regarding this issue?

Comment: This payment gateway comes bundled with Opencart http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=feature/feature&path=8

But the link on the page is broken.

Answer (score 0):

I also posted the same question on the Opencart Forum, Another member just posted a workaround, replacing lines of code in the php file for that gateway.

find out more here.
http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=185&t=150542